# How do I detect if a key is held down in Java 2d?

Tags: java, java-2d

I'm curious if I can tell if a key is being HELD, not pressed and let go.

I need to know this because I'm going to play a shorter mp3 file if it is just pressed and a longer one if it is held.

Thanks in advance!

(I know I asked this for libgdx but I need to know for Java 2d now)

Comment: What do you mean by "Java-2D"? This is more of a description of tools used to display images, not the GUI library. Do you mean to say **Swing** instead? **AWT**? If Swing, the answer is to use Key Bindings which gives you abilities to listen for key presses and releases, both. Start a Swing Timer when the key is pressed.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to register a [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for a press and release trigger. This way you can determine when the key was released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "pressed" vs. "held" is up to you. Many programs even let you configure it. You would have to start some sort of timer when a key was first pressed. If the key is released before the timer completes, you cancel it because the key was only "pressed". If the timer completes, the key was "held". You can use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` for this.